# Категории времен в русском языке

Tags: морфология

Когда мы начинаем учить английский язык, то первое, что приводит нас в ужас, это обилие времен. Все эти "present continius", "past perfect" и т.д. То ли дело русский язык - прошлое, настоящее и будущее.
Но, если вдуматься, в русском языке ведь тоже бывают обороты, вроде "иду я вчера по улице..." или "ты был бы поосторожнее со словами..."
Почему же в русском такие вещи не выделяют в отдельные времена, как в английском?
А на вопрос меня натолкнула такая цитата из интернета:
*"Почему у нас есть будущее время, настоящее и прошедшее, но всё равно настоящим временем мы можем выразить и прошедшее («Иду я вчера по улице...»), и будущее («Завтра я иду в кино»), а прошедшим временем мы можем выразить приказание («Быстро ушёл отсюда!»)? Как точно назвать наклонение с частицей «бы», когда она выражает в разных ситуациях и условие, и просьбу, и желание, и мечтательность, и необходимость, и предположение, и предложение, и сожаление?"*

Answer (score 1):

В русском "такие вещи" не выделяют в отдельные времена, потому что нет отдельных форм глагола для "таких вещей".